# Appended images loaded from file cannot be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using the following script to load images from a folder and append them to a div:

```
$(function() {
    var folder = "img/moreprojects/";

    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
                    $("#gallery").append( "<div class=\"col-12 col-sm-3\" align='center'><img class='img-fluid img-thumbnail img-rounded mx-auto d-block' style=\"max-width: 240px; max-height: 240px; margin: 12px;\" src='"+ folder + val +"'></div>" );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, when I call my next script, which opens a model for the image (which works on images already on the page), the images do not open:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        $('.enlargeImageModalSource').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        $('#enlargeImageModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

How can I have this function, which already works for images in HTML already, work for my dynamically loaded images?

**Note:** I am using Bootstrap 4 and jQuery.

## EDIT

HTML structure (I am using Bootstrap 4):

```
<section class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="gallery">
                <p class="lead">Welcome to our gallery! Here we showcase all the images from our projects and other work. Use the toggles below, to switch between a list view and a swiping gallery view!</p>
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<div class="modal fade" id="enlargeImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="enlargeImageModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="" class="enlargeImageModalSource" style="width: 100%;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your html structure, and the libraries you are using, to be easier to help you ?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to be the response of the ajax request, and what response are you getting ?

Comment: The response is working fine, the images display. It is only the on click call that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `.on('click', ...)` call from:

`$('img').on('click', function() {...});`

to

`$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {...});`

fixed the issue for calling a click event on the dynamically loaded images.